# Windows 7 Folders vs Windows Server Folders Order

Tags: windows, directory

I believe Windows 7 and Windows Server order folder names differently. I am using Windows Server Datacenter.

On a Windows 7 machine I had two folder: 001_SCHEMA and 01_AddFields.  When ordered in ASC order they go 001_SCHEMA then 01_AddFields.  When I copied those folders to the server in ASC order they go 01_AddFields then 001_SCHEMA.

I guess my question is: Is there a bug here or is there some reason to treating sorting differently in desktop and server versions?

Answer (score 1):

My Windows 2008 R2 server sorts the same as yours and Windows 7.

You may want to check if your server has some kind of registry setting that affects Windows Explorer sort order, such as:

**The sort order for files and folders whose names contain numerals is different**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319827